# Is it possible to run my Windows 8 C/go/html program on a tablet

Tags: dll, windows-8, go, driver, cross-compiling

I am writing a program in Go/C for the backend and JavaScript/HTML for the front-end. It is not a web application but it runs a local server which sends data to the client(firefox). The client then displays this data and sends any user interaction back to the server using websockets.

The backend is written partially in C since I have to dynamically load a 32 bit DLL file to communicate with my hardware. The hardware (for which I have aquired both 64 and 32 bit drivers) sends its data via USB to my backend which processes and displays this to the frontend. The hardware, drivers and DLL file are from a third party so my chances of changing any of those are very low.

I use GCC (MinGW) as compiler for the C code since Go and Microsoft's compiler didn't get along very well and I use the 32 bit compiler since I am loading a 32 bit DLL.

The program compiles and runs on my 64 lenovo Thinkpad with Windows 8 professional(running it in legacy mode) but now I wonder if it would be possible to run the same program on a Windows tablet. Unfortunately I don't have a Windows tablet so how can I determine if it will work on a tablet without actually buying one? I know that Microsoft has some sort of emulator but will it work with GCC? Will the processor architecture of the tablet matter? Will the same drivers work? Will the DLL file work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the tablet runs Windows 8. No, if the tablet runs Windows RT. For example,

[Surface by Microsoft - the New Tablet PC](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us)

[Surface Pro specifications](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/surface-with-windows-8-pro/specifications)

[Surface RT specifications](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/surface-with-windows-rt/specifications)

[Which Surface is right for you? - SKU Chooser](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/which-surface-is-right-for-you)